# Why are Custom Restore Point Descriptions Inconsistent?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I have encountered something that I can't explain and I was hoping that someone is aware of this and knows either what is causing it or how it can be mitigated.

#### Background

I have a script that is creating system restore points when run at certain intervals (such on system logon or scheduled task). The restore points are given specific generated descriptions during the creation process without issue.

#### Problem

When I look at the system restore interface, I see them all listed as "*Automatic Restore Point*" <sup>**(1)**</sup> for their descriptions. However, when I click on "*Scan for affected programs*" <sup>**(2)**</sup>, the window that opens, **DOES** show the correct description on the top <sup>**(3)**</sup>.

#### Question

Why the inconsistency? Why isn't the description, that is clearly in there and being shown on the subsequent screen, not showing up on the list of restore points?

Is there a flag that I missing? (aka, Is there a setting or an option that is needed to be flipped to make it show up?) Or is this just a system glitch/limitation?

#### Visual

[image]

Thank you all in advance and I look forward to your insights or potential workaround on this.

---

#### Update: Testing/Findings

[per @MichaelFrank's request using PowerShell]

Issuing the command:

`Checkpoint-Computer -Description "I'm Custom Made" -RestorePointType "MODIFY_SETTINGS"`

The description in #1 shows correctly now as "I'm Custom Made" which appears to suggest that indeed the two descriptions are the same variable, however, why they are showing different while using `command-line` or `vbs` is unclear. The type listed is consistent with others as **System**.

[image][image]

So now the question becomes, why the disparity?

#### Resolution

Until I can figure out the underlying reason for the difference, I have bootstrapped the PS command that seems to correctly produce the results expected into the batch script. Doing this eliminates the need to handle the VBS externally (which is quite robust and OS aware) but in the meantime consolidates everything into a single batch file. So there is that upshot of simplification (even some extended compatibility options are now skipped).

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean. The description column is indeed there and yet the text for description is different, what is this about 4 columns and never been displayed there? Can you clarify?

Comment: Can you post the script or command that you are using?

Comment: @Appleoddity I could but that is not the issue, it is creating it properly and correctly, and the proper description shows on the second window but not on the list, that's the issue I am trying to resolve. I don't know how the code will help but if you can explain, I'd be happy to add it, just don't want to pollute the question with unnecessary information. There are several ways to do it, using the command line or VBS and both result in the same thing, I tested with both methods but settled on VBS as the cleaner option.

Comment: These are the lines that create it `Set SRP = getobject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:Systemrestore")
sOut = SRP.createrestorepoint (sDesc, 7, 100)`

Comment: This is probably the most important part of your question. You asked, “Is there a flag that I am missing?” Let’s start by looking at what you are doing now and go from there. Like you said, there are many ways to do this. Maybe you missed the “right” way.

Comment: What makes you think the two descriptions are supposed to be the same? Perhaps they are simply *both* descriptions, but not the same description.

Comment: @Appleoddity I understand the confusion and I am sorry. The creation only has 3 parameters, nothing more. What I meant was a system flag, something on the OS level that needs to be modified. Sorry I wasn't more clear about it. The creation only takes 3 parameters, one being the description and the other two being the types.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Well, they are both labeled "Description", it was a logical assumption, no? What makes you think they are not? Are you suggesting they are two separate variables independent of each other but with the same label? That's an interesting prospect, but I don't see how that would make sense, although with M$ anything is possible. Any insight on how/if this might be the case?

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ My original train of thought was that they were simple describing the type of restore point. Automatic vs. Manual, etc. However, that might not be accurate. Anyhow, can you attempt to use the Powershell command `Checkpoint-Computer` to set a restore point and see if that works?

Comment: @MichaelFrank I see what you mean and it is possible they have taken the horrible choice of referring to them by the same label, hence my observation confusion. Certainly I can try the powershell method, give me a  bit of time to run that up the flag pole and I will provide some feedback on my findings. I'll try to get to it before the end of the day or when I get home. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Please see the findings updated in the question above. Any further insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.